# How to get float from F() / F() in Django

Tags: python, django

```
queryset = M.objects.annotate(count1=Count(...), 
    count2=Count(...), rat=F('count1') / F('count2'))
```

I find the `rat` is integer, not float. I need 'count1' / 'count2' is float.

I do below:

-- 1. does not work

```
M.objects.annotate(count1=Count(..., output_field=FloatField()),
    count2=Count(..., output_field=FloatField()), rat=F('count1') / F('count2'))
```

-- 2. does not work

```
M.objects.annotate(count1=Count(...), 
    count2=Count(...), rat=Func(F('count1'), 2, function='round') / F('count2'))
```

-- 3. does not work in template

```
{% withratio count1 count2 1 %}
{% withratio count1|floatformat:2 count2 1 %}
```

-- 4. does not work again

```
M.objects.annotate(count1=Count(...), 
    count2=Count(...), rat=F('count1') * 1.0001 / F('count2'))
```

-- 5. wrong

```
M.objects.annotate(count1=Count(...), 
    count2=Count(...), rat=float(F('count1')) / F('count2'))
```

How should I do?

Comment: Error Message like: float only accept 'str' or 'numeric', not F(...)

Comment: are you using python 2 or python 3

Comment: please try like this
F('value1') * Decimal('1.0') / F('value2')
or this 
F('value1') * 1.0 / F('value2')

Comment: follow answer of Arakkal Abu

Comment: i using python 3.7 and django 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`models.ExpressionWrapper`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) as

```
from django.db import models

qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    total=models.Count(...),
    less_total=models.Count(...),
    div=models.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.F('less_total') / models.F('total'), 
        output_field=models.FloatField())
)
```

### Update

to get precision, multiply by **`1.0`** as,

```
div = models.ExpressionWrapper(
    models.F('less_total') * 1.0 / models.F('total'),
    output_field=models.FloatField()
)
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: i using postgresql 12.3

Comment: in postgresql 12.3, ```select 1/3``` return 0, ```select 1::numeric/3``` return 0.3333333